# Converting Table Data to Transaction Data in r

Tags: r, arules

For a current project I am trying to find a way to convert large amounts of table data (300,000+ obs. of 19 variables) into transaction data for arules. A large number of the variables are formatted logically.

I've tried the following from `library(arules)`: `newdata <- read.transactions("olddata.csv", format = "basket", rm.duplicates = FALSE, skip = 1)`

However I get the following error: 
`Error in asMethod(object) : 
  can not coerce list with transactions with duplicated items`

I don't want to remove duplicates as I lose so much of my data because it removes every duplicate logical T/F after the first occurrence.

I figured I could try and accomplish my task using a for loop:

```
newdata <- ""
for (row in 1:nrow(olddata)) {
  if (row !=1) {
    newdata <- paste0(newdata, "\n")}
  newdata <- paste0(newdata, row,",")
  for (col in 2:ncol(olddata)) {
    if (col !=2) {
      newdata <- paste0(newdata, ",")}
    newdata <- paste0(newdata, colnames(olddata),"=", olddata[row,col])}
}

write(newdata,"newdata.csv")`
```

My goal was to have the value of each variable for each observation look as follows: `columnnameA=TRUE`, `columnnameB=FALSE`, etc.  This would eliminate "duplicates" for the `read.transactions` function and retain all of the data.

However my output starts looking like this:

```
 [1] "1,Recipient=Thu Feb 04 21:52:00 UTC      2016,Recipient=TRUE,Recipient=TRUE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=TRUE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE\n2,Recipient=Thu Feb 04 21:52:00 UTC 2016,Recipient=TRUE,Recipient=TRUE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=TRUE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE,Recipient=FALSE\n3
```

Just a note that Recipient is my first variable name in my `olddata` object.  After it does every observation as `Recipient=X` it changes to the next variable name and repeats.  I end up with a file that has over 5 million observations...oops!  This is my first real stab at nested for loops.  Not sure if this is the best approach or if there is a better one.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts or insights you might have.

Comment: How does the file olddata.csv look like? I have the feeling that your file is not in basket format. You need to post at least the first few lines of the file...

Comment: Hi @MichaelHahsler, my olddata.csv file is not in basket format, and that is part of my problem.  I realized that after initially trying the `read.transactions()` as I was doing more research on the error message.  That led me to attempting the for loop to convert my data frame into a transaction / basket format.  So I can then prep it for arules.